# Best way to preview React Native components

Tags: reactjs, react-native, preview, aws-device-farm

I am working with designers on UI components. I am trying to find the best way for them to check React Native components without the need to use actual devices or simulators. Ideally, it will be web-based solutions.

I did some research I found the following solutions.

1. [Expo snack](https://snack.expo.dev/) - the issue is that the components are not publicly available (private npm registry)
2. [React Native for Web](https://necolas.github.io/react-native-web/) - My concern is that component will not render correctly.
3. I am also considering using [BrowserStack](https://www.browserstack.com/). But I can have similar issues as with the Expo snack.
4. [Amazon Private devices](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/working-with-private-devices.html) I don't have a lot of experience with AWS. I need to check is posible to interact with the device using the web.

Any help with this will be very helpful. Is there some open-source solution that I can check?

Thanks.

Comment: https://storybook.js.org/tutorials/intro-to-storybook/react-native/en/get-started/, may help.

Answer (score 0):

Try next extensions

1. [Preview.js](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=zenclabs.previewjs) - not free, but satisfies your requerments.
2. [Component Previewer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Asnow.componentpreviewer) - works, but I cant complitely understand how configure this.